# How to Load More Posts In CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, pagination, uicollectionview

i am making app with Xcode using Swift , i fetch posts from my WordPress Website, i am very new to Xcode and Swift , i have fetched posts from my Website Successfully , now the problem is that when is try to load more posts (More than 10 posts) , i mean pagination, i see some problems, like when i do pagination after 10th post, it show the next 11-20 posts but it not starts from post 11th but it goes directly to post 20 and because of that , all next posts loaded automatically untill the end of posts, and one more thing when next posts are loading than i can't see the old posts like when 11-20 posts loaded then 1-10 posts are not shown and CollectionView starts from number 11.

this is my code to fetch posts..

```
 func fetchPostData(completionHandler: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void ) {
   
    self.page += 1
      let url = URL(string: "https://www.sikhnama.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=6&page=\(page)")!
      
      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
          
          guard let data = data else {return}
          
          do {
              
              let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
              
              completionHandler(postsData)
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.collectionView.reloadData()
                  
              }
          }
          
          catch {
              
              let error = error
              print(String(describing: error))
          }
          
          
          
      }.resume()
      
      
      
      
      
      
  }
```

in ViewDid Load

```
 self.fetchPostData { (posts) in
    self.newsData = posts }
```

and this is how i do pagination

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == self.newsData.count - 1 {  //numberofitem count
            updateNextSet()
        }
}

func updateNextSet(){
   self.fetchPostData { (posts) in
  self.newsData = posts
               }
```

}

CollectionView Code

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return self.newsData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MovieCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCollectionViewCell
    
    
    
    
    
    cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.row])
    
   
    
   
    
    return cell
    }
```

please help . thanks

Comment: https://mobikul.com/pagination-in-swift/#:~:text=Pagination%20in%20Swift%20is%20the,feature%20to%20load%20more%20information.

Comment: @noorapps If I answered your question, please mark it as answered by clicking the tick icon to the left of my answer. This lets others know that the question has been resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the next batch of posts come back, you are overwriting the existing posts rather than appending them:

```
self.fetchPostData { (posts) in
    self.newsData = posts 
}
```

Instead, you need to append the new posts instead such as by using the `+=` operator.

In addition, you should call `reloadData()` within the `fetchPostData` completion handler rather than inside the response of the HTTP request to give your code better separation of concerns.

So the above code would become:

```
self.fetchPostData { (posts) in
    self.newsData += posts 
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: i have removed self.collectionView.reloadData() and it works, thanks a lot